# Как сделать чтобы создавалось div столько-же сколько индексов в массиве?

Tags: php

У меня в бд есть ингредиенты и я вывожу их с помощью preg_split, к примеру Array ( [0] => молоко [1] => сахар [2] => яйца [3] => ) как сделать чтобы создавалось div столько-же сколько индексов в массиве?

Comment: Чтобы приять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него

Answer (score 3):

Используя `foreach`.

```
<?php
$string = "молоко,сахар,яйца";
$ingredients = preg_split("/,/", $string);

foreach ($ingredients as $ingredient) {
    echo "<div>$ingredient</div>";
}
?>
```

Дополнительная информация для изучения: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Все понял спасибо